# Como hago para seleccionar el radio button, se valide, de ahí seleccione un select y al momento de selecionarlo me salga un formulario?

Tags: php, select, botón, radio

Estoy haciendo un sistema de operaciones geometricas, tengo como quien dice la pura interfaz, pero me tiene trabado un select. lo que requiero es que al momento de seleccionar un radio button y un select, me salga un formulario. Por ejemplo: RB: Cuadrado - Select: Área y cuando los seleccione me de un formulario que diga BASE y ALTURA y un Submit.

```
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="cuadrado" > Cuadrado<br/>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="cubo" > Cubo<br/>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="rectangulo" > Rectangulo<br/>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="prisma" > Prisma Rectangular<br/>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="triangulo" > Triangulo<br/>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="figura" value="piramide" > Piramide<br/>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label="select-sm">
        <option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
        <option value="1">Perímetro</option>
        <option value="2">Área</option>
        <option value="3">Volumen</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br/>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Base: <br> <input type="text" name="base">
    <br>
    Altura: <br> <input type="text" name="altura"><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
<?php
?>
```

Comment: Inicializa el `<form>` con un `style="display:none"` y en el `select` le agregas un evento `onchange=` donde detecte cualquier cambio, y si éste se produce que haga un `display:inline;` sobre el `form` para que lo muestre.  Cuando lo tengas, si sigues teniendo problemas, pulsa sobre [edit] en la pregunta y agregas lo que has hecho y nos cuentas que no has conseguido hacer, porque ahora mismo lo que has hecho es nada de nada, y sin errores no se puede dar una respuesta válida.